# Big Query Data Transfer for Google Ads

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

We're currently using google big query data transfer to import google ads data to Google Big Query. In the ads account we're running mostly mobile app campaign, with two type of campaign (acquisition & reengagement).

From what we see the data from **acquisition campaign is successfully transferred to Google Big Query, but the data for reengagement campaign is not transferred at all**.

Our question is, is this a technical limitation from the data transfer itself? Or do we do something wrong in the set up ? AFAIK, during the configuration we only need to connect to the google ads account without choosing which campaign / campaign type that we want to transfer. Any pointer & guideline is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you get any suspicious records looking through DTS [logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-logging)? I expect this case would require in-depth investigation by the technical team, therefore it worth to open the support case via google [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for now.